# Application Variables not being persisted

Tags: coldfusion

**Problem:**

I have 2 files in the same folder:

- index.cfm
- application.cfc

My index.cfm is empty and below is my `application.cfc` code:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
        <cfapplication name="TimeHistory" clientmanagement="No" sessionmanagement="No" setclientcookies="Yes" />

        <cflock scope="application" type="exclusive" timeout=10>            
            <cfset application.test = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
        </cflock>
        <cfreturn true />
    </cffunction>


    <cffunction name="onRequestStart">
        <cfdump var="#application#" label="before">     
        <cfif structKeyExists(URL,  "restart")>         
            <cfset onApplicationStart()>
        </cfif>
        <cfdump var="#application#" label="after">
        <cfabort>       
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

As you can see, I am setting a `test` variable in the `application scope`.

When I call the page with the `?restart` URL query param, this  is the output:

**url:** `../index.cfm?restart`

[image]

Next,I removed the `?reset` URL query param and loaded the page, this  is the output:

**url:** `../index.cfm`

[image]

**Question:**

Should it not have set the variable as part of the first call and then be persisted for future calls? How can I make it do so?

Comment: No. That is not the correct way to set the application name.  Do not use `<cfapplication>`.  That tag is for use with an Application.cfm file.  Instead, set the application name inside the `cfcomponent` tag, before any of the function calls, ie `<cfset this.name = "MyApplicationName">` See the example here http://blog.strikefish.com/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=585F0E1E-E19B-31A5-4357446E2AF47653

Comment: *set the application name inside the cfcomponent tag, before any of the function calls ...* ... As well as any other application settings (setclientcookies, sessionmanagment, ...) of course.

Answer (score 4):

Based on **+Leigh**'s comment , I modified my code which now works. Leaving this here as a solution. Thank you Leigh :)

```
<cfcomponent>
   <cfscript>
       this.name = "TimeHistory";
       this.clientmanagement= "no";
       this.sessionmanagement = "no";
       this.setClientCookies = "no";
       this.setDomainCookies = "no";
   </cfscript>
    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart">                
        <cflock scope="application" type="exclusive" timeout=10>            
            <cfset application.test = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
        </cflock>
        <cfreturn true />
    </cffunction>


    <cffunction name="onRequestStart">
        <cfdump var="#application#" label="before">     
        <cfif structKeyExists(URL,  "restart")>         
            <cfset onApplicationStart()>
        </cfif>
        <cfdump var="#application#" label="after">
        <cfabort>       
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the final code. Side note, though it works either way, you could also stick with all cfml and replace the cfscript section with individual cfset statements :)

Comment: What is the reason for individual cfsets as opposed to cfscript?

Comment: No reason other than preference. I have seen a few folks that mistakenly believed the application settings *must* be done with cfscript ;-) Just pointing out that it is not a requirement. Using all CFML, rather than mix and match, works too.